# Самый быстрый способ получить уникальные значения из двух списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, список

Есть два списка, в которых очень много элементов -  1 000 000 и больше в каждом.

```
a = ['a1', 'a2' , ... , 'a999999']
b = ['a1', 'b2', 'a3', ...., 'a999999']
```

Необходимо получить значения из списка b, которых нет в списке a.

```
c = []
for value in b:
    if value not in a:
        c.append(value)
```

Есть ли способ ускорить сравнение, если учесть, что значений в списках много миллионов?

Comment: например, set(b)-set(a)

Comment: я бы посоветовал https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html , потому что у меня есть подозрение, что эта реализация будет эффективнее разницы сетов.

Comment: Если списки отсортированы хоть каким-то образом (и мы знаем каким), то можно идти параллельно по спискам и выводить разницу. А так разница set-ов самое то.

Comment: @splash58 Может добавите таки в виде ответа, что вопрос как неотвеченный висит )  Хотя наверняка дубликат чего-нибудь

Comment: наверняка, дубликат. А автору уже тоже всё равно :) Их не удаляют - неотвеченные?

Comment: @splash58 Не удаляют, так и висят, иногда всплывают в ленте либо после редактирования кем-то либо по неведомому алгоритму сайта

Comment: @CrazyElf нашел дубликат

Answer (score 0):

Можно отсортировать один массив за nlog(n), и, проходя циклом по неотсортированному массиву сравнивать с отсортированным, ища в последнем doubling или бинарным поиском. Получится nlog(n) на сортировку 1 массива + m*log(n) на поиск = (m+n)  * log(n) сложность, что меньше квадрата, но не факт что быстрее :))

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться операцией симметричной разности для двух множеств

```
    (set(a) - set(b)) + (set(b) - set(a))
```